# Preventing implict construction for function arguments

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a class which has several constructors, one accepting a string:

```
AClass(const std::string& str);
```

and I have a function which requires an instance of `AClass`:

```
void AFunction(const AClass& a);
```

Question

I just inadvertently passed a completely unrelated string object, instead of an `AClass` but there were no compiler errors because of `AClass`'s string constructor.

Is it possible to generate a compiler error if the function is called passing a string:

```
std::string s("");
AFunction(s);
```

because I would like it to require an actual `AClass` object:

```
AClass a;
AFunction(a);
```

or

```
AFunction(AClass(""));
```

Comment: Is it an option to make `AClass(const std::string&)` an `explicit` ctor?

Comment: Mark your constructors `explicit` (in general you should do this for all single argument constructors)

Comment: `explicit` is the keyword you are looking for. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit

Comment: Thank you everyone. I have seen `explicit` but wasn't 100% sure how to use it. @lorro as you were first if you put an answer i'll accept. Thank you Alan and Jesper.

Comment: @intrigued_66 One sec, I'm doing it but I'll provide you one more possibility. (thx)

Comment: You could also define an overload of the function taking `std::string const&` as deleted, but the big benefit of the explicit constructor is that it works for every function taking this kind of parameter: `void AFunction(std::string const&) = delete;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pragmatic way is to make the constructor `explicit`:

```
class AClass {
public:
    explicit AClass(const std::string& str) {}
};
```

If, for some reason, you cannot touch that code, then you might resort to a ref-holder class:

```
#include <iostream>

// unchanged
class AClass {
public:
    AClass(const std::string& str) {}
};

// this holds a const T& value
// note: cannot be used with temporary!
template<typename T>
struct ExplicitFrom {
    ExplicitFrom(const T& t) : value(t) {}
    const T& value;
};

//instead of: void AFunction(const AClass& a) {}
void AFunction(const ExplicitFrom<AClass>& a) {}

int main() {
    std::string s;
    AClass a(s);
    AFunction(a);

    // AFunction(s); // error
}
```

Comment: The second alternative may not provide you with a good error message. There's a possibility of changing that: define a template overload that contains a `static_assert` permitting only `AClass` and subtypes: https://godbolt.org/z/dexashazG

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming that for whatever reason the class should not be modified by adding `explicit`.)

Since C++20:

```
#include<concepts>

void AFunction(const std::same_as<AClass> auto& a) { /*...*/ };
```

This makes the function an (abbreviated) function template, so it should be defined in the header if shared between compilation units. You can also additionally explicitly instantiate it, in which case it can still be defined only in the translation unit with the explicit instantiation:

```
template void AFunction(const AClass& a);
```

---

Alternatively, if you still want to allow objects of a type derived from `AClass` to be passed without requiring an explicit conversion, then you can use `std::derived_from` instead of `std::same_as`, but then, because you can't know the derived classes up-front, you can't use the explicit instantiation approach.

Comment: Wouldn't this also prevent subclasses of `AClass` from being passed? Use `std::derived_from` instead...

Comment: @fabian Yes, could also be what OP wants. I wasn't sure. The problem with that is that explicit instantiation is then not a possibility anymore. A user can still cast to `AClass&` explicitly if they want to call this function.